# Why does my layout get cut off when I resize my browser?

Tags: css, layout, browser

If you go to http://digitaldemo.net/anova/ and resize the browser to make it smaller and then scroll horizontally to the right, you will see that the background now covers the part of the page outside the wdith of the visible screen.

Why is this happening?

Any help would be most appreciated!

Best,

Cynthia

Comment: The content simply does not fit, it is too wide.

Comment: no, that isn't what I mean

Comment: Hang on, I'll do screen cap

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this.

```
#navbar{ min-width: 1100px; }
```

same to .footer, .wrapper, and .footerbottom
min-width:1100px

Comment: It worked! Now can you explain to me WHY it worked so that I remember it from now on? Thanks so much!

Comment: you set the divs to 100%, they are then relative to the window's width. But if you make the window really small, like 600px, your divs will only have 100% width, which is 600px. If you then scroll to the right, your you're scrolling past the 600px, hence the layout problem

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because the `#nav` element has a hard width of `1100px` and a `width:100%` background on another element is only `100%` of the width of the viewable area.

Changing the `min-width` on the `<body>` to

```
body {
     min-width: 1100px;
}
```

will set your minimum page width to be the length of your longest element and therefore the CSS background will extend as it will be `100%` of `1100px` wide.

For future projects I'd recommend reading [responsive web design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) - one aspect being to design a site will adapt to the available width/height of a device, through a combination of non-fixed dimensions on elements and/or [CSS Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: I'll be using CSS media queries. I'm trying to get the non-mobile layout nailed down first, though. But I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just debugged your code and found out the issue. The issue is you are using `overflow:hidden` property. It is causing problem. like in class (.masthead) you apply this. Just remove it. then it is visible.

Comment: where am I using display:hidden ?

Comment: I saw two three places. for example - in class .masthead

Comment: `hidden`is not a valid value for `display`, only for `visibility`. For `display`, it would be `none` to completely hide an element.

Comment: I am not using display:hidden. I've used overflow:hidden